# Bike Pedal Falling Off

Tags: pedals

While riding her bike my daughter's pedal came off. It appears to be stripped. This has happened to her with a total of three bikes. What could be causing this to happen?

Comment: A total of three bikes, meaning three different bicycles have lost a pedal? Are these bicycles being put together by the same person?

Comment: Yes three different bikes and they were assembled at the store. All bought at different stores at different times. Two of the bikes were one year old and the other was new.

Comment: Is there any chance that some mechanically inclined person is giving the bikes a tune-up that involves tightening the pedals?

Comment: No. She takes it out and rides it then brings it back in the house. We don't leave our bikes outside and we don't attempt maintenance until something goes wrong.

Comment: I don't think it likely that these bikes were of such poor quality that the pedals just shear off spontaneously. (Though, I find it less likely that some vandal is targeting just the pedals of your daughter's bicycles.) Even cheapo resin pedals will go four or five years before breaking... and even then it takes a special dedication to strip a pedal out of a crank. Is it always the left pedal, or the right pedal?

Comment: Two left and one right. She's afraid she is riding them wrong, if that is even possible.

Comment: What kind of store are you buying them from? Are these  Walmart quality bikes, or are you buying them from a bike shop? I wouldn't be surprised if bikes from  Walmart were assembled poorly with pedals overtorqued or cross threaded and stripped - even across multiple purchases. And it could take some time for it to finally fail. But a bike shop should know better.

Comment: 1. Did you buy the same make from the same shop three times...urban myth would be that the factory had 3 faulty bikes in 10000 mass produces and you got those!

Comment: Even bikes from big box stores shouldn't have pedal problems like this. They're more likely to have problems with things that have to be finely tuned like bearings and spoke tension. Since they're being assembled by different people, I think it has to be something that you or your daughter is doing, although I have no idea what it could be.

Comment: The only thing I can imagine is that someone is getting the pedals swapped right/left when assembling the bike, or possibly the pedals are simply not tightened enough.  Pedals are installed in the store, sometimes by a store employee and sometimes by an itinerant bike assembler, so improper assembly is not at all out of the question.  (There's no way that how your daughter rides the bike could cause this unless she's a 500 pound gorilla.)

Comment: (In any event, this is definitely a defect in the bike, as delivered, and you should demand full "satisfaction" from the store, even after a year.)

Answer (score 5):

The only time I've seen pedals in a newish bike strip out of the crank was when the mechanic who assembled the bike overtightens the pedals (the mechanic was a younger me, but you live and you learn.) Often, people will forget that left pedals are left-hand threaded and will strip them out when they try to remove them.

The mechanical motion of pedaling causes metal-metal mating surfaces to fret - microscopic motion back and forth causing noticeable wear. If this were a bike from the 70's with aluminum cranks it wouldn't be a surprising failure mechanism. However, since these are new bikes, the most likely explanation is that who ever assembled these bikes tightened the pedals too much. There is no way a child could be riding the bicycle enough to cause a pedal to strip out. To have it happen three times is incredibly unlikely, though.

I'd avoid buying department store bikes and refer to your local bike shop for any repairs or replacements.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is a matter of how well the person that assembled the bikes tightend the pedals. Sometimes, assemblers do not tighten some bolts enough, for example, or they may tighten them unequally. So accidents occur while riding...

Please check the whole bike before getting out of the store, because sometimes, they think that we are completely stupid and do stuff like this. Majority of them only care about our money. There are some exceptions, but sadly they are very rare.

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se]! We recommend that new members take the [tour] to make best use of the site, and since you're answering see [answer] also.

Comment: When it happened multiple times with multiple stores, a generic bit of advice like "check the bike" isn't an adequate answer. The rant part is irrelevant.